# How to set timezone in kibana plugins

Tags: kibana-5

We can update timezone in kibana application using advance setting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html
But this timezone is not applicable to Timerange in custom kibana plugins,it always display time as per browser timezone.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the Kibana core doesn't correctly set timezone for all apps so need to set timezone in custom  kibana plugins as  following ,use config as DI in controller or service

`import moment from 'moment-timezone'`
`moment.tz.setDefault(config.get('dateFormat:tz'))`